# Using existing string from main.strings file for another element's text

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I added a label (let's call it as 'newLabel') to my storyboard and added text (let's say 'Share') for it as well. I even had Localization checked for all languages in the storyboard, but still the text didn't get added to Main.strings(en) file and hence didn't get translated.

But my main.strings(en) file already has the text 'Share' which I had added for another label (let's say 'oldLabel') and that text is localized and present in main.strings file for other languages.

Is there a way where I can access that string from main.strings file and assign it to label's text property via code?

**oldLabel's text in main.strings(en) file:**

[image]

**What I want to know is if something like below is possible in the code?**

```
newLabel.text = nuq-zS-uwp.text
```

If yes, then how do I access nuq-zS-uwp.text in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access localized strings in code using calls to NSLocalizedString, like

```
let localizedShareString = NSLocalizedString("nuq-zS-uwp.text",
    value:"SHARE", 
    comment: "Share string")
```

That will work as long as the localized strings file from your storyboard keeps the same key, and is in the app bundle at runtime.

However, I suspect those auto-generated string key names are fragile and subject to change.

In my company we generally ignore the strings in Storyboards and replace them with strings we look up in code using `NSLocalizedString()`.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Yeah I hate accessing the string this way, but my company had a string freeze already and now I cannot add new strings. So I either display the text in English even for other locale's or I access existing string and assign that to the label's text.